# Customwait - Check element is visible/disappear with selenium webdriver (element is in the DOM, but not visible)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to implement a custom wait method which should wait till a loading popup is visible.

This loading popup has its own id = "wait". I use this custom expectedConditions (from Stackoverflow) to check it:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> absenceOfElementLocated(
            final WebElement element) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                try {
                    element.isDisplayed();
                    return false;
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    return true;
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "element to not being present: " + element.getText();
            }
        };
    }
```

My script pass on when the loading still visible and I do not know why.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use WebDriverWait for pausing the execution till an expected condition to be true.
ex:
      WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,30000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yourPopUpId")));

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but does not work. Driver cannot recognize the popup change..

Comment: Try with JavascriptExecutor, and perform operations

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpectedConditions#invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

You can also use negation -> [ExpectedConditions#not(ExpectedCondition condition)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-)

A basic example:

Go to this page: [Primefaces - dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml)
There is `Submit` button on this page, if you click on this button, then `Selected` message will appear on the screen, then this message will dissapear after a few seconds.
So we will wait in our code for the following events:

- the button appears and is clickeable (it cannot be clicked until it is not clickeable)
- the message appears and is visible
- the message disappears an is not visible

---

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

try {
    driver.get("https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml");

    final By buttonSubmit = By.xpath("//button[ *[ text() = 'Submit' ]]");
    final By message = By.xpath("//span[ text() = 'Selected' ]");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonSubmit)).click();
    System.out.println(String.format("Button clicked after %d miliseconds", System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(message));
    System.out.println(String.format("The message appeared after %d miliseconds", System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

    // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(message));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(message)));
    System.out.println(String.format("The message dissapeared after %d miliseconds", System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

} finally {
    driver.quit();
}
```

---

And a result is:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 15827
.....
.....
.....
Button clicked after 153 miliseconds
The message appeared after 791 miliseconds
The message dissapeared after 6924 miliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried all expectedconditions but as I mentioned before, driver cannot recognize the difference of popup states. I used Id. What do you think, should I use xpath instead? I know it should not modify anything, I'm just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why your code isn't working without more of the code. You do have some logic errors in your custom wait but you don't need that custom wait because `ExpectedConditions` already has visibility and invisibility covered.

Use this to wait for the popup to appear

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wait")));
```

Use this to wait for the popup to disappear

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wait")));
```

There are times when a popup is just a container for dynamically loaded content. In these cases, you might wait for the frame of the popup to appear but the contents of the frame are not quite loaded yet so if you try to interact with them, you will get errors. In those cases you will need to wait for an element inside the container to be visible.

Same thing for when a dialog is closing. I've had experiences where I've waited for the dialog container to close but the grey overlay is still up blocking clicks, etc. In those cases I had to wait for the overlay to become invisible.

I would suggest that you spend some time familiarizing yourself with the available methods of `ExpectedConditions` and save yourself having to write custom waits for things that already exist and don't need to be debugged/tested.

Comment: Hello Jeff, thanks for your reply. The main problem, all the mentioned methods does not work, hence I tried custom wait methods. ExpectedConditions are pretty straightforward, but not in this case. I guess, (only assumption) the main problem, this wait element is always in the dom, I can find it in the source every time, every page, just the visibility is changing and webdriver cannot recognize the differences. I tried these methods with other sites, and works like a charm, but in this case, I cannot use it. Some trick is needed to solve this question. with some Javascript?

Comment: The element may always be in the DOM but that doesn't mean that this method won't work. Selenium can tell the different between present and visible/invisible. Please share the site or an example site so I can see.

Comment: I cannot share it unfortunately, but I will check some examples.